# Comparar ciclo while y diferenciar en tabla

Tags: php, html, mysql

explico a continuacion mi problema.

**Tengo este tabla**

```
while($ROW = $QueryResultmsd->fetch_assoc()){

                    printf ("<tr>");
                    printf ("<td style='background-color:#00ce36;'>".$ROW["nparte"]."</td>");
                    printf ("</tr>"); 
              }
```

**Con esta consulta:**

```
$Querymsdafter="SELECT * FROM com.sensitivos
WHERE id_model='".$_GET["modelo"]."'";  
$QueryResultmsd=mysqli_query($con,$Querymsdafter);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y genero esta otra tabla:

```
<?php

                    while($rowTx = $QueryResultmsdNxt->fetch_assoc()){
                    
                    printf ("<tr>");
                    printf ("<td style='background-color:#00ce36;'>".$rowTx["nparte"]."</td>");
                    printf ("</tr>");
                }
              
            ?>
```

Consulta Mysql:

```
$QuerymsdnxtNx="SELECT * FROM com.sensitivos
WHERE id_model='".$_GET["modelonxt"]."'";   
$QueryResultmsdnxtnxt=mysqli_query($con,$QuerymsdnxtNx);
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero lograr es comparar los while de dato "Id_model" de una tabla con otra, que los datos que se repitan en una el background cambie de color, yo logre hacer esto con el while pero solo me compara el dato con el mismo que esta en su fila, tienen alguna idea?

Estoy haciendo esto:

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i < $ValueBucle; $i++) { 
    while($rowNextMsdnxt = $QueryResultmsdnxtnxt->fetch_assoc()){
        while($rowTx = $QueryResultmsd->fetch_assoc()){
            if ($rowNextMsdnxt["nparte"] == $rowTx["nparte"]){
                $BckMs = '#00ce36';
            }else{
                $BckMs = '#ff6b6b';
            }
        printf ("<tr>");
        printf ("<td style='background-color:".$BckMs.";'>".$rowTx["nparte"]."</td>");
        printf ("</tr>");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Con esto:

```
<?php
//**Conexion **//
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","com");

$QueryBucle="SELECT *,  COUNT(nparte) AS NumberOfProducts 
FROM com.sensitivos WHERE id_model= '28572071A'";

$ResultQueryBucle=mysqli_query($con,$QueryBucle);
$Rowbucle = $ResultQueryBucle->fetch_assoc();
$ValueBucle = $Rowbucle["NumberOfProducts"];

$Querymsdafter="SELECT * FROM com.sensitivos
WHERE id_model='28572071A'";  
$QueryResultmsd=mysqli_query($con,$Querymsdafter);

$QuerymsdnxtNx="SELECT * FROM com.sensitivos
WHERE id_model='28572072B'";   
$QueryResultmsdnxtnxt=mysqli_query($con,$QuerymsdnxtNx);

?>
```

Pero al encontrar el pprimero valor que coincide se sale del bucle y no continua.

Comment: Ya leí esta pregunta antes. Almacena los datos de los selects en arrays y luego en un for recorres esos datos y si son iguales los pintas.

Comment: Modifique el post a ver si puedes orientarme un poco

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Pero, viendo tantas consultas, me pregunto, ¿por qué no armas una sola consulta donde verifiques lo que tengas que verificar, relacionando las tablas si fuera preciso y luego muestras los datos? Las bases de datos tienes funciones potentes que te permiten hacer verificaciones, existen también los `JOIN`, etc. ¿Por qué no haces uso de ello en vez de lanzar tantas consultas para luego ponerte a manipular datos y más datos? Una de las principales características de las bases de datos es que son **relacionales**, pero me parece que estás ignorando esa ventaja.